# Where does output go when running the C program with the DE2?

Tags: c, ide, nios

When I run this program in the Nios 2 simulator I get the expected output (1.000000).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  float  n=0; 
  printf("%f\n", ++n);
  return 0;
}
```

But when I run the program on the board it doesn't output anything at all in the IDE console. Where does output go? Isn't output supposed to display in the IDE console?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a configuration error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `n` as

```
float  n=0.0f;
```

it will work.

Comment: Of course it didn't work. My environment sucks, not even code formatting works.

Comment: I think its the problem of IDE. I tested it on many compilers.

Comment: I got it to work now. I changed the IDE configuration. The .ptr file for configuration must match a .sof file or i/o won't display. Now itäs working.